# I want to install something by npm, but it says 'error' and 'checkPermissions Missing'

Tags: node.js, npm

its my first post, so im not sure whether right way to answer im doing or not ..haha

```
Jongryului-MacBook-Pro:~ jongryulpark$ npm install uglify-js -g
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
```

as a title, i don't know why it makes error..

```
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jongryulpark/.npm/_logs/2018-10-18T01_28_56_508Z-debug.log
Jongryului-MacBook-Pro:~ jongryulpark$
```

to fix this i googled, and heard about nvm.. but that doesnt work neither

Comment: Remove node, to then install with nvm then all will be ok

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Macbook React Native install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48029088/macbook-react-native-install)

Answer (score 1):

Try running the command with sudo.

> sudo npm install