# (Why) is it a bad idea to allow node sudo access with third party packages?

Tags: node.js, react-native, sudo

(I am not sure if this is the correct stack exchange forum to post this question; please let me know if you know a more appropriate forum.)

I am trying to install react-native on mac OSX and am receiving an error. This specific question is [QnA'd here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48029088/macbook-react-native-install), and is also solved [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19588). I am already using homebrew (per the example in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)) and solution #3 failed for me. I am a bit hesitant to use sudo (as suggested in the first link) due to my inexperience. In the second link (above), a user stated:

> sudo will solve this, but you should not be using that. This means
>   node was installed in the wrong way. You should try to uninstall node
>   and install it via homebrew. Allowing node sudo access with third
>   party packages is just stupid.

Instead of taking this statement at face value, I wanted to understand why this could be the case. What exactly does it mean to allow node sudo access with third party packages, and why is this a "stupid" idea?

Answer (score 0):

(I think this question is better go to [Unix & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com), but I am also not sure.)

The command `sudo` will gain a temporary **root** privilege on the executed command, which the executing program will have full control to the device. If a third party have some harmful action, it may cause a disaster if you give it the full access with `sudo`.

Besides, there has already been a report (a news report [for example](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/11/26/npm_repo_bitcoin_stealer/)) about crypto-mining code inside several Node.js NPM packages. So this warning has a real history before.

Comment: Should I delete this post before asking there?

Comment: @allthemikeysaretaken Sometimes I can see a post in other site marked as "migrated from stackoverflow.com", but I also not sure how to "migrate" :-(